# How does the sum of closed walks change when a new vertex is added to a subgraph?

Tags: algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, algebraic-combinatorics

Suppose I calculate the sum of all closed walks from vertex i in a subgraph of some graph (the subgraph is composed of a subset of vertices from the graph and all edges between those vertices from the graph).

Now I add one further vertex to that subset and find the new subgraph in the same way. I calculate the sum of all closed walks from vertex i in this new subgraph.

Are there results which can tell me anything about how much the sum of closed walks to i increases by when the new vertex is added?

(I feel like there must be an intuitive result here that breaks down walks in the subgraphs and says how they combine to give the increase in the number of walks.)

Comment: This is very unclear. What do you mean by the "sum" of closed walks; how do we add closed walks. Also the number of closed walks that use a vertex is infinite if the conected component of the graph that contains $i$ has at least two vertices in it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and pointing to the lack of clarity in the question. More precisely (I hope): I am considering a graph where each edge has weight $\gamma<1$. I count the number of closed walks from i of length k multiplied by $\gamma^k$. Then I calculate the sum over all k: $$ \sum_k  \gamma^k \cdot \text{ number of closed walks from i of length k } $$